What is the differences between these two read char by char functions in C?
There are two functions that supposedly read a string character by character. The issue lies on the different nuances in the result. Whether the one with the while loop discards further characters after entering a new line character, the second of the for loop stops saving in the array the characters when '\n' but somehow if this function is requested again it prints directly the leaving characters of the previous time before being able even to type yourself.
You may try the program by changing the functions and check that the difference in the output is evident but I don't understand.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int read_lineD_Solution(char str[], int n);
int read_line(char str[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    char a[100] ;

    printf("Enter a sentece: ");

    read_lineD_Solution(a, 3);

    printf("%s\n", a);

    printf("Enter a sentece: ");

    read_lineD_Solution(a, 3);

    printf("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}

int read_line(char str[], int n)
{
    int ch, i=0;

    while ((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
        if (i < n)
            str[i++] = ch;
    str[i] = '\0';
    
    return i;
}

int read_lineD_Solution(char str[], int n)
{
    int ch, i;

    for (i=0;i<n; i++) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n')
            break;
        str[i] = ch;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

I tried to change the while loop for a "for" loop and vice versa. Also I changed the order of the conditions. Both approaches rendered me a similar output but with unexpected behavior.

The main difference is that the while loop will read a whole line, but will throw away any character after you have read n characters; But the for loop will leave the rest of the line in the input buffer when it has read n characters.

By the way, is the code you show a copy-paste of the actual code you build and run? Because you never call read_line. You call read_lineD_Solution twice instead.

Enter a sentece: hey dude
hey
Enter a sentece:  du

I mean to try twice read_line and twice read_lineD_solution

Output with read_line:

Enter a sentece: hey dude
hey
Enter a sentece: hey dude
hey

Output with read_lineD_solution

Enter a sentece: hey dude
hey
Enter a sentece:  du

Please edit your question to include your output. Comments are not suitable for that.

[Edit] your question to add information like input and output (both expected and actual).

Both may write to str[n] so must be passed no more than 99 to stay in bounds

Use a debugger to step through both functions line by line to see what really happens.

So the difference is within the kind of loop or rather the conditions?

read_line() reads up to the end of the line: '\n'
read_lineD_Solution()  reads up to the end of the line '\n' or n characters, whichever is first.
Both have a bug: When n characters read, str[i] = '\0'; writes past buffer when n is the buffer size.
Both do not well handle getchar() returning an EOF, which should end the read.
Pedantically both functions are ill behaved when n <= 0.

Tip: Useful to add sentinels to output to help detect white-space.
// printf("%s\n", a);
printf("<%s>\n", a);


Both functions ends either '\n' or i == n;

@PepeCuesta One loop ends when you reach a newline. The other ends when i == n or you get a newline.

@PepeCuesta "Both functions ends either '\n' or i == n" --> No.  read_line() only ends with reading '\n'.  There is no test of i to end the loop.

In read_line, you always consume input through the next newline character:
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' )

but you only store the result in the buffer if you've read less than n characters so far:
if (i < n)
  str[i++] = ch;

In read_lineD_Solution, you consume up to n characters or through the next  newline, whichever comes first:
for (i=0;i<n; i++) {
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '\n')
        break;

So the two functions can leave the same input stream in different states.  Assume the input stream contains "This is a test\n???":

After calling read_line with n equal to 3, a will contain the string "Thi" and the input stream will be "???" (because you've consumed everything through the newline character);

After calling read_lineD_Solution with n equal to 3, a will contain the string "Thi" and the input stream will be "s is a test\n???" (because you only consumed 3 characters);


It basically comes down to what state you want to leave the input stream in after you finish reading input; do you want to clear the input stream completely through the next newline, regardless of how many characters you actually store?  Or do you want to leave unread characters in place for a following read?
BTW, regardless of which solution you use, you will want to add a check against EOF, otherwise bad things can happen:
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF )

or
if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF )
  break;

